# Having trouble with displaying data in table with each function

Tags: jquery, json, function, html-table, each

I know this is a silly question and I apologize for my limited knowledge in Javascript and programming in general.

I have a search that gets a value you enter and then uses it to search the db and returns the data in a table. So if I search banana it will display banana and it's values like fat, fiber etc. in a table, creating new rows for each search. Now, the problem I'm having is that if I search for let's say 3 items in the end I'll get 6 rows instead of 3, because the table will fill up with all the previous searches.
This is the part of the code that handles this:
It's part of the html file

```
     <script>

function funkcija(){
var value = $('a').text();

$('#hidden1').show();



$('#jedinice_butt').click(function(){
var odabrano = $("#dropdown option:selected").text();

var uneseno = $("#input_jedinica").val();
$('#tablica').show();




if(odabrano === "g"){

alert(value);
$.getJSON("nutritional_value.php?value=" + encodeURI(value), function (data) {
var ttr = $("<tr />");   
$.each(data, function(k, v){

    $("<td />").text(k=='name' ? v : v * (parseFloat(uneseno, 10) / 100)).appendTo(ttr);

});

$("#tejbl").append(ttr);
}); 



} 
}
</script>
```

part of the html:

```
 <div id="search_result">

    <a href="#"></a>

</div>

<div id="hidden1">


        <form name="input" action="" method="get">
             <input id="input_jedinica" type="text" name="namirnica">
             <select id="dropdown">
                <option value="kg">g</option>
                <option value="dg">dg</option>
                <option value="g">kg</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" id="jedinice_butt">ok</button>
        </form>

</div>
</div>


<div id="tablica">
<table id="tejbl">

<tr id="naslov">
<td><h3>NAME</h3></td>
<td><h3>FAT</h3></td>
<td><h3>FIBER</h3></td>
<td><h3>SUGARS</h3></td>
</tr>


 </table>
 </div>
```

So how do I do it without having it output all of the previous searches every time I search for one item?

php for the second search, nutritional_value.php:

```
<?php



    include 'connect.php';


    $value = $_GET['value'];


   $query = mysql_query("SELECT NAME, FAT, FIBER, SUGARS FROM ccm WHERE NAME LIKE '$value%'");
   while( $run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){


        $results = array();
        $results["name"]=$run['NAME'];
        $results["fat"]=$run['FAT'];
        $results["fiber"]=$run['FIBER'];
        $results["sugars"]=$run['SUGARS'];
        //Send it to the client in json format:
        echo(json_encode($results));

  }




    ?>
```

php file for the first search:

```
<?php 

include 'connect.php';

$value = $_POST['value'];

echo '<ul>';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT NAME FROM ccm WHERE NAME LIKE '$value%'");
while( $run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $name = $run['NAME'];


    echo '<li onClick="funkcija();">'.$name.'</li>';


}

echo '</ul>';
 ?>
```

jQuery for the first search:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#search_button').click(function(){
    var value = $('#search_box').val();

    if(value != ''){
    $('#search_result').show();
        $.post('search.php', {value:value}, function(data){
            $('#search_result a').html(data);


        });
    }
    else{
        $('#search_result').hide();
    }
});


   });
```

Comment: $("#tejbl").html(ttr); ???

Comment: @dewd Yes it is only declared withing the function. How do you mean dummy data? :P

Comment: @dewd well it get's it from the php file which does a query in the db.
here:
name     fat     fiber   sugars

broccoli 0.3846   3.33    1.41

banana    0.3389   2.62   12.2

Comment: mmm, could your 'value' contain the previous query as well as the current query?

Comment: `.append` will add the new table row.  `.html` should replace the contents of `#tejbl` entirely.  What does it do instead?

Comment: @ExplosionPills it's not meant to overwrite the previous results, it's meant to append. it's just appending the previous data as well as the current. At least that's my interpretation of the issue.

Comment: @dewd it's meant to append, but you're complaining that it's appending?  I don't get it

Comment: @ExplosionPills It's meant to append only the results it's just got. Not those results plus the previous results which are already attached.

Comment: @dewd the value is set from the text of a link and I get the link when I search for something so I'm not really sure, let me alert it after a few searches.

Comment: @dewd so what you're saying is that there is data there to begin with and he appends the first result to it, but from then on he only wants to replace appended data instead of what was there in the first place?  Why not just create a separate element that starts out empty to append to/

Comment: @ExplosionPills I tried html and I got the same result

Comment: @Filkatron Could you clarify the issue a bit more? Do you want the rows of previous searches to stay? And the issue is that they stay but get duplicated with every search? Or is the issue simply that data from the previous searches should be overwritten?

Comment: @dewd the data in the table (row) should stay from the previous search, but the thing that's happening here is that it additionally displays all of the searches I made
So if I search banana, it will display banana in a row (thats good) then when I search broccoli I get banana broccoli and banana. And I only want banana and broccoli in the table :s

Comment: Okay I did a alert(value); and indeed the value fills up with all the searches I do... So that's the problem here :S

Comment: @Filkatron Cool. You ok debugging the issue with the value getting appended to?

Comment: @dewd Dude, I would if I knew how to :S I'm not very good at this. I'm a beginner so to say. :/

Comment: I just checked my console and when I search for the first time "nutritional_value.php?value=" is being called once, but when I search it the second time it gets called twice

Comment: @dewd I think I got what you meant and I changed the line to this:
$("<td />").text(value).appendTo(ttr);  
First time I search for broccoli and I get a row full of broccoli, second time I search for banana and I get another broccoli and a banana row

Comment: http://snag.gy/auWKJ.jpg

Comment: @Filkatron sounds like your issue is with whatever calls the function which wraps this then? Sounds like it's calling or iterating to $.getJSON once for each previous time the search has taken place.

Comment: Yeah.. But dunno, I edited the question with more code and the html. Could you check if you see what's doing it maybe? If not, thanks for your help so fat :)

Comment: Just putting my children to bed. Back soon.

Comment: If you checked the picutre the input field is used for the first search and the output from it is being put in #search_result in the link. 
Then the value is set to the text of the link.
I tried putting the var value = $('a').text(); in the click function even in the if but the same thing occurs.

Comment: I don't see the code which adds to the link. Sounds like its that  code which is the root of your issue. Can you post it?.

Comment: Here, I edited it, first search php and jQuery for the first search, also added the rest of the second js script and the php for it

Comment: I think I just need a way to reset the variable value after each click. I think that would solve this problem, but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this in `function funkcija()`: Remove `$('#jedinice_butt').click(function () {` and paste it into your `$(document).ready(function () {` at the top is fine. then add `funkcija()});` to it so you have `$(document).ready(function () {funkcija()});`. You seem to have a `);}` missing from the bottom of `funkcija`. A copy and paste error? If it's in your actual code you just need to remove the last `});` Your final code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#jedinice_butt').click(function () {funkcija()});

$('#search_button').click(function () {
    var value = $('#search_box').val();

    if (value != '') {
        $('#search_result').show();
        $.post('search.php', {
            value: value
        }, function (data) {
            $('#search_result a').html(data);


        });
    } else {
        $('#search_result').hide();
    }
});


 });



function funkcija(){
var value = $('a').text();

$('#hidden1').show();

var odabrano = $("#dropdown option:selected").text();

var uneseno = $("#input_jedinica").val();
$('#tablica').show();




if(odabrano === "g"){

alert(value);
$.getJSON("nutritional_value.php?value=" + encodeURI(value), function (data) {
var ttr = $("<tr />");   
$.each(data, function(k, v){

$("<td />").text(k=='name' ? v : v * (parseFloat(uneseno, 10) / 100)).appendTo(ttr);

});

$("#tejbl").append(ttr);
}); 
}
}
```

Comment: it didn't work. I did! Look at the last two code blocks.
the php outputs the name echo '<li onClick="funkcija();">'.$name.'</li>'; and the jQuery then handles that information (data): $.post('search.php', {value:value}, function(data){
            $('#search_result a').html(data);

Comment: I get this: [22:53:03.066] <ul><li onClick="funkcija();">broccoli</li></ul>

Comment: so if you inspect element on <div id="search_result"><a href="#"></a></div> you see: <div id="search_result"><a href="#">[22:53:03.066] <ul><li onClick="funkcija();">broccoli</li></ul></a></div> ??

Comment: And when you click broccoli: in your alert(value), you get "[22:53:03.066] <ul><li onClick="funkcija();">broccoli</li></ul>"?

Comment: I have an OK button but yes, when I click it I only get broccoli, because the value gets text();

Comment: Try setting value to $("#dropdown option:selected").text(); instead of $('a').text();

Comment: It's like the $.getJSON function in the script is being called for how many times I have searched before, when I get to the third search it calls the php three times for just one search. :s

Comment: Okay, I did it, on the second search it calls the php two times with the value "g". What the hell

Comment: i'm going to try and move your code to a fiddle to see if i can recreate the issue. i'm flying a bit blind i've a few theories, but i really need to test them.

Comment: good news. i can recreate the issue. just seeing if i can debug it :)

Comment: That's awesome :D
If you solve it please explain me what happened :P
:)

Comment: i think it's the jedinice click function. I think it's in the wrong place.

Comment: i've edited the answer to show what your JS should look like.

Comment: No problem. Glad we got to the bottom of it. It's hard when you can't test the code. As soon as I tested it, it was very straight forward. Should have noticed the position of that click function earlier though. Have a good week. :)

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine :/ Thank you, you too! :D